# MS Word exportasfixedformat PDF clear form field's result and save PDF with empty values

Tags: vba, pdf-generation, ms-word, formfield

I create document in MS Word 2007, then insert there text form field.
I use this controls to programmatically put text in different places of document.
Then I put some text inside form field

In code:

```
name = Document.Formfield(j).Name;
if (name=="ground")
    Document.Formfield(j).Result = "some text"
...
```

[image]
Then go to menu, Save As PDF.

After saveing Form Field's text is empty, and PDF is empty, WTF (What The Feature)?

How to save PDF with text in form fields?

Comment: in which language is your code written? it is not word-vba for sure. I guest it is C# therefore my suggestion is to check if there isn't any other event which is triggered before export and which action results with cleaning your field.

Comment: It is RSL, the property of R-Style Softlab. My code is used inside one of it's product. The syntax is simple, so I sure programmers understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by code replacing Form Field by its Result:

```
        i = ND.FormFields.Count;

        while (i > 0)
            ND.FormFields(i).Range = ND.FormFields(i).Result;
            i = ND.FormFields.Count;
        end;
```